# Pass an argument to a Rules Action using VBO

Tags: 7, rules, actions, views

If I create a Rules Action to set the value of a CCK field, and point to that action from VBO, is there a way to add user inputs to the VBO form on the views page to pass parameters to the Rules Action?

I would prefer a way to do this through GUI if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explaining how to create Rule that accept arguments (user can enter any value) and adding VBO field in Views: [The Power of Rules with Views Bulk Operations (and Commerce)](http://vimeo.com/26884701)

From [Joren](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1693/joren) comment:

```
 function modulename_form_views_form_test_view_page_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
    $form['#submit'][] = 'modulename_vbo_submit'; 
    $form['select']['arg'] = array( '#type' => 'textfield', '#title' => t('Whatever') ); 
 } 
 function modulename_vbo_submit(&$form, $form_state) { 
   $nids = $form_state['selection']; 
   foreach ($nids as $nid) { 
     $node = node_load($nid); 
     rules_invoke_component('rules_test', $node, $form_state['values']['arg']); 
     drupal_goto('test-view');
   } 
 }
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed. The only missing piece is getting the form field to be on the same page as the view. I don't like the intermediate step for entering that value.

Comment: well, in this case you can only write custom module.

Comment: Can the custom module just move the form to the views page, but the rest of the functionality come from the Action? If so, do you know how?

Comment: I assume you can catch VBO form in Views via hook_form_alter and adding input box there, then adding own submit with calling rules action.

Comment: I can't figure out how to call a rules action. :\

Being able to add arguments is great, but having it be a separate step makes it fairly poor for something users are supposed to use.

Comment: Figured it out. Put this in your answer so I can credit you: function modulename_form_views_form_test_view_page_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['#submit'][] = 'modulename_vbo_submit';
 $form['select']['arg'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Whatever')
 );
}

function modulename_vbo_submit(&$form, $form_state) {
 $nids = $form_state['selection'];
 foreach ($nids as $nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  rules_invoke_component('rules_test', $node, $form_state['values']['arg']);
  drupal_goto('test-view');
 }
}

Comment: I assume $form_state['selection'] = $form_state['values']['selection']

Comment: If you need to write code as above, then don't use VBO at all (since you're going completely around everything it offers), and just write a custom Views Form field handler instead (like Views Send for D7 does).